# Trusting packages in Jackson2JavaTypeMapper

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

Everything is working fine when I trust all packages using '*' but I'd like to trust only my domain's package. This is what I tried and its not working

```java
if (javaTypeMapper instanceof DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper) {
            javaTypeMapper.addTrustedPackages("com.domain");
```

Exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The class 'com.domain.service.dto.name.SomeDto' is
> not in the trusted packages: [java.util, java.lang, com.domain]. If you believe this
> class is safe to deserialize, please provide its name. If the serialization is only done
> by a trusted source, you can also enable trust all (*).

How can I trust everything under the package com.domain?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I trust everything under the package com.domain?

You cannot.

The package must be fully specified `com.domain.service.dto.name`.